# Escaping double quote in argument value for flyway

Tags: node.js, powershell, flyway

Trying to run on powershell: `flyway -password='pass"word'`

Result: `The syntax of the command is incorrect.`

**How to escape argument values for flyway in case of double quotes?**

Using flyway 5.2.4 on win 10 x64.

Comment: Try with escaping the double quote inside the single quotes: `flyway -password='pass\"word'`

Comment: @Theo Believe me, I have tried most solutions google has to offer. Not working. I think it is related to flyway, not the shell. Making a topic here was the last resort, I tried to make it a simple as possible.

Comment: I cannot try this myself, but I think you need to single-quote the whole thing after `flyway` like this: `flyway '-password='pass"word'`. Took that from [here](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1670)

Comment: @Theo Have also tried that before, nope (i think you have typo there too).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at issues on the Flyway GitHub repo, I found [this](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1670#issuecomment-309207197) which suggests that the following should work:

```
'-password=pass"word'
```

You didn't give a clear example of what your password is so my best guess is your password is `pass"word`.